# Responsive Navbar in React and Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently working with a React application and Bootstrap. The index file of my website only contains `<div id="app"></div>` and some scripts.

I want to implement a responsive navbar in `app.js` with `data-toggle`, but I not sure how to do that.

```js
var Navbar = React.createClass({
displayName: 'Navbar',
render: function() {
return el.nav(
    {className: 'navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top'},
    el.div(
    {className: 'container'},
    el.div(
        {className: 'navbar-header'},
        el.a({className: 'navbar-brand', href:'/'}, config.app_name)
```

```html
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
```

How do I make this responsive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Bootstrap Case</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js">   </script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
</div>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
<h3>Inverted Navbar</h3>
<p>An inverted navbar is black instead of gray.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

use Bootstrap JQuery fonction you don't have to write it on your own